# React Native FBSDK open App Invite Dialog in Webview

Tags: react-native-fbsdk

Is it possible to open the app invite dialog in the native facebook app or webview, similar to `ShareDialog.setMode("webview")`?

Currently the invite dialog launches the Safari browser, and has lead to issues such as having to log in again or not going back to the app but staying on Facebook after sending invites.

Thanks!